# How to display image horizontally in block div?

Tags: css

I have a grid parent block:

```
<div class="grid">
   <div><a><img></a></div>
   <div><a><img></a></div>
</div>

.grid{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 200px);
    gap: 10px;

}
```

I try to display images horizontally no depends size. Now I get images by full size.

I tried to set height for `div` as `div {height: 140px}` and `img {width: 100; height: auto; object:fit:cover}`

Comment: you are missing `%` for the image width

Comment: Check out please question again

Answer (score -1, accepted):

if you want the image to be responsive to its container use relative units

try this

```
img {
   height: auto;
   width: 100%;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this on your CSS to rotate the element 90 degres:

```
transform: rotate(90deg);
```